# Broadcast receiver to check internet connection is called twice when i disconnect wifi

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

This is the `BroadcastReceiver` for checking internet connection, it displays "No Internet" toast twice when I disconnect wifi.

`InternetDetector`.java

```
package com.hfad.evenit;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Vicky on 26-Sep-15.
 */

public class InternetDetector extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public InternetDetector() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        boolean isVisible = MyApplication.isActivityVisible();

        try {
            if (isVisible == true) {
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                // Check internet connection and accrding to state change the
                // text of activity by calling method
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hfad.evenit" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".EnterPhoneNumber"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EnterVerificationCode"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_enter_verification_code"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GetNameAndEmail"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_get_name_and_email"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Launcher"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".InternetDetector"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Intent filters for broadcast receiver -->
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have tried several solutions but none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is mentioned in Android docs this broadcast can be send whenever connection state has changed but also when device is moving from mobile data to WIFI and so on.

> Changes to a device's connectivity can be very frequent—this broadcast is triggered every time you move between mobile data and Wi-Fi.

[source](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

There is plenty of states in connection, al of them can be found [in docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html)

To check current state of network connection you should use [getActiveNetworkInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()).

So your method to check state may look like:

```
 private void checkNetworkState(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(activeNetworkInfo == null){
        //no network
    } else {
        NetworkInfo.State state = activeNetworkInfo.getState();

        switch (state){
            case CONNECTED:
                break;
            case CONNECTING:
                break;
            case DISCONNECTED:
                break;
            case DISCONNECTING:
                break;
            case SUSPENDED:
                break;
            case UNKNOWN:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Remember about permission: `android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`

Comment: Dude there is no problem in your method `checkNetworkState`, the problem is it will be called twice as `BroadcastReceiver` is called twice, so it will produce two toasts again.

Comment: No, it will not be called twice if you will check actual state of network. And yes the broadcast will be called many times, once for state DISCONNECTING and second time for DISCONNECTED. It is your responsibility to react on them.

Comment: @ jakubbialkowsk Ok, just think about this, i open the app and i switch off my wifi -`BroadcastReceiver` called once as wifi is disconnected. Now system will check if mobile data is available , suppose it's off as well then again `BroadcastReceiver` is called again. So the state `CONNECTED` will be true twice. If i react to `CONNECTED` state it will be executing twice. What do you think?

Comment: @Vicky, it will not be called twice for wifi and mobile, it will be called once with the type of network so you may and may not use this information (whether is wifi or mobile)

Answer (score 5):

The `ConnectivityManager` sends various intents to inform about different states, so it's normal, you're not catching only the internet on/off change, this feature has more than this options, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) for more details.

**UPD**, here is the solution:

```
public class InternetDetector extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public InternetDetector() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
        boolean isVisible = MyApplication.isActivityVisible();

        try {
            if (isVisible == true) {
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                // Check internet connection and accrding to state change the
                // text of activity by calling method
                if ((networkInfo != null) && (networkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
                   Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                   Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So what should be the proper solution?

Comment: Sorry dude, it doesn't.

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thanks in advance man for your sincere efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I guess can help this. I have update your Receiver. Let try this sure help you.

```
package com.hfad.evenit;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Vicky on 26-Sep-15.
 */

public class InternetDetector extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private boolean isConnected = false;

    public InternetDetector() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean isVisible = MyApplication.isActivityVisible();

        try {
            if (isVisible == true) {
                isNetworkAvailable(context);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        if (!isConnected) {
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Now you are connected to Internet!");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Internet availablle via Broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            isConnected = true;
                            // do your processing here ---
                            // if you need to post any data to the server or get
                            // status
                            // update from the server
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "You are not connected to Internet!");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet NOT availablle via Broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isConnected = false;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Dude it will not work as the broadcast receiver is called twice, the method `isNetworkAvailable` will also be called twice and hence producing two toasts.

Comment: I checked it, It does not work,it produces two Toasts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable `b` to remove duplicate action.

```
boolean b = true;
if(b){
   // do something, in the first trigger
}else{
   //do nothing, cancel trigger
}
b = !b;
```

Comment: Yes, this is the logic.Ok, i'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: When app is not running, and BroadCastReceiver "wakes is up" the `b` will be `true`, e.g. if he will close the app after first check, therefore, this is not logical thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver connectivityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        boolean isConnectedToData;

        final int currentType = activeNetwork != null
                ? activeNetwork.getType() : NO_CONNECTION_TYPE;

        if (sLastType != currentType) {
            if (activeNetwork != null) {
                boolean isWiFi = ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI == currentType;
                boolean isMobile = ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE == currentType;

                if (isWiFi || isMobile) {
                    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
                    if (isConnected) {
                        isConnectedToData = isConnected;
                    } else {
                        isConnectedToData = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    isConnectedToData = false;
                }
                // TODO Connected. Do your stuff!
            } else {
                // TODO Disconnected. Do your stuff!
                isConnectedToData = false;
            }
            sLastType = currentType;

            if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {
                connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnectedToData);
            }
        }

    }
};
```